# Windows will not startup after symbolic link of installation folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link

I did a symbolic link of the Installer folder which is in the Windows folder on my C drive, which I moved to my E drive. Everything seemed to be going well, but after I restarted my pc it just doesn't turn on. I cannot seem to do a system restore or even a clean reset.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you have a windows install medium, boot into that. If not, create one from another pc using the Media Creation Tool, which you can download from the Microsoft site.

Once you have booten into Windows Setup and you are presented with the very first setup screen (I believe its the license agreement), hit ALT+F10 or SHIFT+F10, and a command prompt will popup. From there delete the symbolic link and move the data back.

Once restored, just turn off the computer and boot normal again and all should be fine again.

Its the only way. A few folders will break windows if you turn them into symbolic links. They are C:\Program Files (and x86 version), C:\Windows (and everything inside) and C:\ProgramData.